# How do we make dygraphs work as well in the mobile browser as in the desktop browser?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Dygraphs is awesome to use in the desktop browser.

There is rollers.

You can do shift+drag to pan.

You can select a part of the graph to zoom by using click and drag.

The bad part is none of these work on a mobile chrome browser.

It says in the website that it can allow pinch.

When I tried pinching, there is heavy delay, and it goes haywired.

There is no rollers showing in the mobile version as well.

How do I use dygraphs in the mobile browser as well as the one in the desktop browser?

Comment: Hello, u found any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Hello, no. What about you?

Comment: Nope still looking for free license mobile chart framework..

Comment: the same problem here